# Java Postgresql Runtime Error

Tags: java, postgresql, runtime-error

I have a couple of java applications that use a postgres database. They have worked fine on many computers, but I have come across 1 computer that is throwing a runtime error. I have double and triple checked my database configurations and haven't been able to find an error.

The code that I run that throws the error is:

```
this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.connectionStr,
                    this.username, this.password);
```

where this.connectionStr is previously set to be

```
this.connectionStr = "jdbc:postgresql://" + this.server + ":"
                + this.port + "/" + this.database;
```

I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be great.

The runtime error is as follows where PostgresHandler.java:70 is the code I showed above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa der.java:58) Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.StrictMath.floor(D)D
        at java.lang.StrictMath.floor(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Math.floor(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.dtoa(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Double.toString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.Provider.putId(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.Provider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.Sun.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou rce)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.postgresql.util.MD5Digest.encode(MD5Digest.java:46)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(Connect ionFactoryImpl.java:328)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(Conne ctionFactoryImpl.java:95)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactor y.java:66)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Conn ection.java:124)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Conn ection.java:30)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Conn ection.java:29)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:386)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at db.PostgresHandler.connect(PostgresHandler.java:70)
        at db.PostgresHandler.<init>(PostgresHandler.java:47)
        at db.DBInsertHandler.<init>(DBInsertHandler.java:16)
        at Server.main(Server.java:62)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your classpath, be sure that the driver jar is installed on the problem server/host.

A reflection error usually means you misspelled a class name, or forgot to add the library with the class.  Not that I've ever done that  :-)

Alternately, maybe you have an older version of the driver that does not fully implement a newer interface???

Comment: This fixed it for me. However, the root of the issue was that there were multiple version of java including both the JDK and JRE and because of this the external jar I needed wasn't being referenced correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Eclipse's jar-in-jar loader. Have you tried running this with the first level JAR file exploded?

If that works, something is going on with un-jaring multiple levels of a jar file. The only thing I can think that would cause that is a virus scanner.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are running a pre 5.0 version of the JVM.  The version of the jar you are using depends on StrictMath which came in at 5.0.  Are you using a 1.4 jvm?